# I want to write multiple queries results one after another in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

For ex : if there are 3 sql statements and it produces 2 rows per each sql.. it should display the result in below format

```
Row 1 from sql1
Row 1 from sql2
Row 1 from sql3
Row 2 from sql1
Row 2 from sql2
Row 2 from sql3
```

I tried union thinking it may help but it prints first sql statement results and goes to next one.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of `ROWNUM` here:

```
SELECT <COLUM_LIST> FROM
(SELECT <COLUM_LIST>, ROWNUM AS RN, 1 AS QUERY_NUM from table1 -- sql query 1
UNION ALL
SELECT <COLUM_LIST>, ROWNUM AS RN, 2 AS QUERY_NUM from table2 -- sql query 2
UNION ALL
SELECT <COLUM_LIST>, ROWNUM AS RN, 3 AS QUERY_NUM from table3 -- sql query 3
)
ORDER BY RN, QUERY_NUM
```

If you want to define specific order of record in each query then instead of `ROWNUM`, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` analytical function.

Cheers!!

Comment: side note; you don't need the outer query. A union B union C order by x will be fine

Comment: I took outer select to remove `rn` and `query_num` column from final output.

Comment: Welcome and keep coding :)